# Get command object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am writing a spring 2.5 application and in my jsp I'm writing my own tags.

It's about a list of objects...when I change the number of rows that list shows(a combobox), I am doing a submit on my form returning back to the view(obviosly with the new number of rows returned).

When listing with my own tags I need to get the properties from my command object.
I have access to the pageContext object but I can't figure where the command object is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the command object is stored under a "command" attribute (request or session scope depending on your configuration of the [sessionForm](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/AbstractFormController.html#setSessionForm%28boolean%29) property). You can change that by setting the [commandName](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/BaseCommandController.html#setCommandName%28java.lang.String%29) property on your controller and your command object will be included in the model under this name (and not the default "command").

Once in your tag code, you can use `request.getAttribute("command")` or,  if sessionForm=true,  `session.getAttribute("command")` to get access to your command object (assuming the default name "command"). If you changed the name of the command using the `commandName` property then use that instead of "command".

Usually you wouldn't care in what scope the command is, so having access to the pageContext object, you can do a `pageContext.findAttribute("command")` and that will look it up in all scopes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
I have founded the command object, but now I'm facing another problem. Let's say I have a list of objects, first I display only 10 of them. When the user clicks on 'next' button it will show it the next 10 items(i make a submit on the form). My problem is that when it first enters on the controller I found the command object but on the second time(after submit-into the tags) it doesn't, I receive null. I solved the problem by putting on the request in the controller the command object, so that in the tags I allways find it after submits. Do you know another way?thanks